# Document database for ARM Debian

Tags: nosql, arm, debian, document-oriented-db

Lately I started writing an application for which document database seems like a perfect match for data storage.

I wanted to use MongoDB but as I later discovered there is no proper package for my "hosting machine" (Sheeva Plug with debian on it).

I was looking around the web for something similiar to mongoDB but couldn't find satisfactory result.

Anyone knows any document database that runs on ARM?
Python module is welcomed addition.

Ps. 
CouchDB is a no.
I know there is non-x86 Mongo package on git but it is also a no.

Comment: Why don't you try and build mongodb from source?

Comment: @Masta79: MongoDB does not officially support ARM yet. You can vote/watch the Jira issue [SERVER-1811](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1811) for this.  For an embedded device with limited memory (Sheevas are ~512Mb?) you would be better using something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or another lightweight [Python persistent data storage](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+persistent+storage).

Comment: @dogrizz: You may ask a question on `debian-embedded@lists.debian.org`